# Question about Tao's An Epsilon of Room

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, reference-request

The contents of the first half of the book are exactly what I am interested in. Is it suitable for self-study as a stand alone text? I haven't had any prior exposure to functional analysis. Should I supplement it with a more standard textbook?

Comment: That book is just a publication of his blogpost, isnt it? If so, I highly recommend you for using some standart book on e.g. functional analysis (more over, Tao's lecture notes on real analysis, you can easily find it in his homepage)

Comment: @Rick_Student I was under the impression that the first half of the book is based on his real analysis notes.

Comment: If so, it seems to me normal to read and study only this first half of the book and when you really become interested in some special topics in real analysis you can just google it or ask more specified question about references. If you are not satisfied yet, you should examine books like Paul Halmos book or Bogachev Measure Theory. The first one is in fact a list of problems. The second one is big, detailed book.